# Speeding up acast() call to create matrix

Tags: r, plyr, reshape2

I am using the `acast` function within Hadley's `reshape2` package to transform a flattened dataset (queried from SQL Server) into a term-document matrix like so:

```
## Load packages
require("reshape2")
require("plyr")
require("RODBC")
require("lsa")

## Get flattened term-frequency data:
Terms <- read.csv(url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/263772/flat_dtm.csv"), header = T)
names(Terms) <- c("id", "Term", "Frequency")

system.time(terms.mtrx <- acast(Terms, id ~ Term, sum, value.var = 'Frequency')) # re-cast to a term-document matrix
```

The issue I'm bumping up against is that the dimensions of the `terms.mtrx` are very large... 40,000 rows x 17,000 columns, and the matrix is very sparse.

```
> head(Terms)
                      id                      Term Frequency
1 resume-108008-34530496           enterprise data         2
2 resume-108008-34530496 enterprise data warehouse         2
3 resume-108008-34530496                       etl         2
4 resume-108008-34530496                  facility         1
5 resume-108008-34530496                   faculty         1
6 resume-108008-34530496                 financial         1
>
> dim(Terms)
[1] 6139039       3
```

Is there a faster (less memory-intensive) way to generate this matrix??

Comment: It would he helpful if you could actually create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) since we don't have access to your input. Even fake data would be fine. Are you trying to make a proper `TermDocumenMatrix` as in the class from `tm` or are you just trying to make your own array. Perhaps using `xtabs(..., sparse=TRUE)`  would be a better choice than `acast` to create a proper `sparseMatrix()` object.

Comment: @MrFlick I have updated the original with a link to a .csv file in my public Dropbox folder. This should thus be reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an a system that doesn't support https in base R, so to access the data, I used

```
library(httr)
Terms <-content(GET("http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/263772/flat_dtm.csv"))
names(Terms) <- c("id", "Term", "Frequency")
```

And then I compared `acast` and `xtabs(...,sparse=TRUE)`

```
system.time(terms.mtrx <- acast(Terms, id ~ Term, sum, value.var = 'Frequency'))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   9.253   0.199   9.662 

system.time(terms.mtrx2 <- xtabs(Frequency~id+Term, Terms, sparse=TRUE))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.083   0.009   0.092
```

and we can see that

```
all(terms.mtrx == terms.mtrx2)
# [1] TRUE
```

so the results are the same.

Comment: And today I learned what `xtabs` does! Thanks for this! This works great!